# Structure representing time without date in Python

Tags: python, time

Is there in Python data structure to represent only hour minute and second without another info, if not then what structure is best to use in my case?

Comment: Is it supposed to store integers only, does it need to ensure validity, do you plan to convert it to another representation or do date calculations?

Comment: Do you need to support minutes at all? What is your usecase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the `datetime` module and its relevant features for that:

```
from datetime import datetime
my_time = '05:43:34'

my_time = datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S', my_time)
```

Then you can simply do things like:

```
>>> my_time.hour
5

>>> my_time.minute
43

>>> my_time.second
34
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Why the downvote? Anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: Why use `datetime.datetime()` instead of `datetime.time()` here? The OP asked for a type that represents *just* time, not a date and time.

Comment: `time.strptime()` doesn't exist.

Comment: I am still puzzled as to why `strptime()` is used when the OP asked for a data structure. Nowhere is parsing being mentioned.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, As I have shown in my code, the `.hour`, `.minute` and `.second` features can be used along with many others (such as timedelta) for easy time management.

Comment: Sure, but it is a strange and (in my eyes) unhelpful answer to the question *what datastructure to use to represent **just** time*.

Answer (score 9):

The [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) offers several types to represent dates and time, the [`datetime.time()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) may fit your needs here:

```
from datetime import time

afternoon_tea = time(16, 30)
```

If you are trying to represent *durations*, you can use [`datetime.timedelta()` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta); these can be used to adjust `datetime.date()` or `datetime.datetime()` objects:

```
from datetime import timedelta

halfday = timedelta(hours=12)
```

You could also just represent your time as an integer, representing seconds:

```
onehour = 60
```

This all depends on your use cases, which you didn't include in your question, unfortunately.