# Initializing list with data returned by datetime.strptime() in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have python module:

```
import datetime
timeList = [
            [".US",datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','15:30'), datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','22:00')],
            [".PL",datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','09:00'), datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','16:50')],
            [".CZ",datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','09:00'), datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','16:20')],
            [".DE",datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','09:00'), datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','17:30')],
            [".ES",datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','09:00'), datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','17:30')],
            [".IT",datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','09:00'), datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','17:30')],
            [".PT",datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','09:00'), datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','17:30')],
            [".UK",datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','09:00'), datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','17:30')],
            [".FR",datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','09:00'), datetime.strptime('%H:%M:%S','17:30')]]
```

And code in another module using data presented above:

```
for timeData in tradeHours.timeList:
     ...
```

I've got an error:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute strptime().

How to fix it?

[EDIT]:
After fixing my code looks like this:

```
import datetime

INSTRUMENT_TYPE = 0
TIME_BEGIN = 1
TIME_END = 2
timeList = [
            [".US",datetime.datetime.strptime('15:30:00','%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime('22:00:00','%H:%M:%S')],
            [".PL",datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00:00','%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime('16:50:00','%H:%M:%S')],
            [".CZ",datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00:00','%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime('16:20:00','%H:%M:%S')],
            [".DE",datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00:00','%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime('17:30:00','%H:%M:%S')],
            [".ES",datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00:00','%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime('17:30:00','%H:%M:%S')],
            [".IT",datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00:00','%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime('17:30:00','%H:%M:%S')],
            [".PT",datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00:00','%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime('17:30:00','%H:%M:%S')],
            [".UK",datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00:00','%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime('17:30:00','%H:%M:%S')],
            [".FR",datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00:00','%H:%M:%S'), datetime.datetime.strptime('17:30:00','%H:%M:%S')]]
```

datetime.strptime is good for my requirements and better than datetime.time, because I'm using date in format '%H:%M:%S' in my program and no need any conversion in few places.

Comment: Why use `strptime` **at all**? Why not use `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 15, 30)`, for example? That's the same result, without a more expensive parse call. And while you are at it, you could then use `datetime.time(15, 30)` instead of using `datetime()` objects.

Comment: I need hour, but I don't want to use date, because I want to compare only hours.

Comment: Then again, I ask the question *why use `strptime()` here then?*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217545/structure-representing-time-without-date-in-python

Comment: Ah, I see, that's not a very helpful answer. To be fair, your question there is lacking context.

Comment: There is no need to post your fixed code; just mark an answer that helped you most as accepted instead. :-)

Comment: If you want to specify the times as strings instead of constructing `datetime.time()` objects directly then at least remove the code duplication e.g., define `T = lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, '%H:%M:%S').time()` and use it later `time_list = [[..., T('15:30:00'), T('09:00:00'), ..]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it as:

`datetime.datetime.strptime(...)` instead

Alternatively, you could do:

`from datetime import datetime`

and then you can do:

`datetime.strptime(...)`

Comment: After improve it, I've got ValueError: time data %H:%M%:%S does not match format 15:30.

Comment: @CppMonster, Well it __does not__. Do `%H:%M` instead

Comment: I need seconds, but when I do '15:30:00' I have the same error.

Comment: @CppMonster,Flip the order. String goes first. Pattern goes second in `strptime`

Answer (score 1):

You imported *just* the module `datetime` but are trying to call a class method on the *class* `datetime.datetime`; you'd adjust your reference or your import (as well as your parsing pattern, there are no seconds in your string literals):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('%H:%M','15:30')
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('%H:%M','15:30')
```

However, since you are dealing with *hours and minutes only*, I'd use a `datetime.time()` object instead, and just create these as literals:

```
from datetime import time
timeList = [
    [".US", time(15, 30), time(22)],
    [".PL", time(9),      time(16, 50)],
    [".CZ", time(9),      time(16, 20)],
    [".DE", time(9),      time(17, 30)],
    [".ES", time(9),      time(17, 30)],
    [".IT", time(9),      time(17, 30)],
    [".PT", time(9),      time(17, 30)],
    [".UK", time(9),      time(17, 30)],
    [".FR", time(9),      time(17, 30)]
]
```